Division prometheus without matching labels
I have two prometheus metrics nodes_threadpool_rejected , nodes_indices_index_total and  want to perform
nodes_threadpool_rejected/ nodes_indices_index_total
left side metric nodes_threadpool_rejected has nodename and right side metric nodes_indices_index_total  has node. I want to match nodename with node when doing .
Eg : left side nodename="1.2.3.4-es",nodename="2.3.4.5-es" right side node="1.2.3.4-es",node="2.3.4.5-es". I want to do division when nodename and node matches
left side metric result
{cluster_type="search_cluster", job="os_search", nodename="1.2.3.4-es", prometheus="os/prometheus-infra", threadtype="bulk"}

right side metric result
{cluster_type="search_cluster", job="os_search", node="1.2.3.4-os", prometheus="os/prometheus-infra"}

Is this possible ? I read https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching but no clue

You mean that label nodename in left is the same as label node in the right? ANd all other label are the same?

@markalex There are no common labels. But nodename on leftside and node on right side represents same. I want to match rows based on nodename on leftside , node on right side and do the division

What "represents same" means exactly? Do they have the same value? Or partially the same? Or is this a semantically the same, but strings are not related? Recommend to [edit] question and put answers to these questions there.

yes they are having same value

Assuming you have a typo in one of the labels, and they are in fact are the same, you can "rename" label in one of the metrics, and the match on it. nodes_threadpool_rejected/ label_replace(nodes_indices_index_total,"nodename","$1","node","(.+)")

This worked for me
nodes_threadpool_rejected / on(nodename) label_replace(nodes_indices_index_total,"nodename","$1","node","(.+)")

on(nodename) -> match entries on right/left side based on nodename label
label_replace(nodes_indices_index_total,"nodename","$1","node","(.+)") --> This replaces node with nodename on right side.
Thanks @markalex for guidance
